# Update the values of nested hashmap in Java

Tags: java

I need to update a nested hashedmap based on values taken from a file. I have am able to get the correct values from the file but only the last value gets updated to all the header values in the hashedmap. Where is the error in my code? The code is as below:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ParseMap {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> hMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String header = "";
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "file.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.contains("CallMade")) {
                    String[] words = line.split(",");

                    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
                        if (words[i].startsWith("CallId")) {
                            header = words[i];
                        }
                    }
                    hMap.put(header, innerMap);
                }
                else if (line.contains("details") && line.contains(header)) {
                    String[] words = line.split(",|:");
                    System.out.println(header);

                    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println(words[i]);
                        if (words[i].equals(" Agentdetails")) {

                            HashMap<String, String> inMap = hMap.get(header);
                            if (inMap == null) {
                                hMap.put(header, inMap = new HashMap<>()); 
                            }
                            inMap.put("Agent", words[i+1]);
                            inMap.put("AgentID", words[i+2]);                                
                        }
                    }
                 }
           line = reader.readLine();
           }
           reader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(hMap);
    }
}
```

**file.txt**

```
[Call  ] 15:40:35.688 CallMade,Telenet,,CallId53,123456789,5674,02Apr
[CallId53 ] Agentdetails,John,12,21
[Call  ] 15:42:39.324 CallMade,Airtel,,CallId54,123456789,5674,02Apr
[CallId54 ] Agentdetails,James,10,20
[Call  ] 15:43:39.324 CallMade,Airtel,,CallId55,123456789,5674,02Apr
[Call  ] 15:43:40.324 CallMade,Airtel,,CallId56,123456789,5674,02Apr
[CallId55 ] Agentdetails,Jimmy,5,100
[CallId56 ] Agentdetails,Robert,18,120
```

Here if I print the values of words list then I get the correct values but if I print the hashedmap after putting the values then only the last value of **Agent** and **AgentId** is put to all headers in the hashedmap. How to rectify the error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did try this code before but getting the same results: `hMap.get(header).put("Agent", words[i+1]);
                            hMap.get(header).put("AgentID", words[i+2]);`

Comment: You are adding the values to the same key while populating the hashmap. Obviously the previous values for the same key gets overwritten and only last one is retained

Comment: If I use `get` method on header then I will get the `innerMap` value of that particular `header` right? Then I am putting the values into `HashMap hMap(header)(innerMap)`.

Comment: If you can post the contents of file.txt it would be helpful

Comment: OK, I get it now. You are just adding `innerMap` - the same object - as the value to all of your headers. As such, every time when you do `hMap.get(header)` for any header, you get the same object and you just fill it with new values. All the headers map to the same object.

Comment: @HariPrasad Added file.txt

Comment: @RealSkeptic So should I create a new instance of `innerMap` everytime in the `else if` statement?

Comment: You should create a new instance when there is nothing assigned for that header. You actually have the code for that, but the fact that you use the same empty `innerMap` in your `if`  prevents it from happening. Nevertheless, the logic is unclear as it seems it is only going to use the last header anyway. It's hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want the output like this: `{CallId53={Agent=John,AgentId=12}, CallId54={Agent=James,AgentId=10}, CallId55={Agent=Jimmy,AgentId=5}, CallId56={Agent=Robert,AgentId=18}}`. Can you tell me what changes I should make in the code to get the above output?

Comment: @Laxman Did you add `[Call  ]` and `[CallId53 ]` to clarify or does your txt file actually look exact like posted above?

Comment: @Eritrean Yes. It looks like this only.

Comment: Small thing (but not), use try with resources on BufferedReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As IMO your text file is well structured and all call details are listed before the coressponding Agent details I will recomend something like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader reader;
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> hMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith("[Call ")){
                String callId = line.split(",")[3];
                hMap.put(callId, new HashMap<>());
            }
            else if(line.startsWith("[CallId")){
                String callId = line.substring(line.indexOf('[')+1, line.indexOf(']')).trim();
                hMap.get(callId).put("Agent", line.split(",")[1]);
                hMap.get(callId).put("AgentId", line.split(",")[2]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(hMap);
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer!!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying the get the header value from the previous line. That may not be case as in line number 5 & 6 in your file.txt. So I modified the code to pick the CallId from the details line itself. Here is he modified code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ParseMap {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> hMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        //HashMap<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String header = "";
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "C:\\Sandbox\\Stack Overflow\\src\\file.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.contains("CallMade")) {
                    String[] words = line.split(",");

                    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
                        if (words[i].startsWith("CallId")) {
                            header = words[i];
                        }
                    }
                    hMap.put(header, null);
                }
                else if (line.contains("details")) {
                    String[] words = line.split(",");

                    // Pikcing the header for the line itslef
                    header = words[0].replace(" *",  "").split("\\[|\\]")[1].trim();
                    System.out.println("header=" + header);
                    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println(words[i]);
                        if (words[i].contains("Agentdetails")) {

                            HashMap<String, String> inMap = hMap.get(header);
                            if (inMap == null) {
                                inMap = new HashMap<>();
                                hMap.put(header, inMap); 
                            }
                            inMap.put("Agent", words[i+1]);
                            inMap.put("AgentID", words[i+2]);                                
                        }
                    }
                 }
                System.out.println(hMap);
           line = reader.readLine();
           }
           reader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(hMap);
    }
}
```

Output

> {CallId56={Agent=Robert, AgentID=18}, CallId55={Agent=Jimmy,
>   AgentID=5}, CallId54={Agent=James, AgentID=10}, CallId53={Agent=John,
>   AgentID=12}}